# Async function does not execute - Expo React Native

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, native, expo

I developp an app which worked well until I reload one time the application on Expo. I don't understand why the takePicture function is not executed :
In the console I can see STEP 0, STEP 1 but not STEP 2 ...

```
   <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          alignSelf: 'center',
          height: 70,
          width: 70,
          borderRadius: 35,
          backgroundColor: colour.primary,
          borderColor: '#fff',
          borderWidth: 3
        }}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log('STEP 0');
          this.takePicture.bind(this);
          console.log('STEP 1');
          this.setState({pictureTook: true});
        }}
      >
        <Text style={sty.flipText}></Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>  




 takePicture = async function() {
      console.log('STEP 2');
    if (this.camera) {
      console.log('STEP 3');
      this.camera.takePictureAsync({base64: true}).then(data => {
        FileSystem.moveAsync({
          from: data.uri,
          to: `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}photos/IdCard.jpg`,
        }).then(() => {

            Vibration.vibrate();
          });
      });
    }
  };
```

I noticed that I reload a lot of time my app with async functions and AsyncStorage module. Could it be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring an anonymous function for the `onPress` method of `TouchableOpacity`,

```
() => {
    console.log('STEP 0');
    this.takePicture.bind(this);
    console.log('STEP 1');
    this.setState({pictureTook: true});
}
```

and inside it you are binding the the `this` context of `this.takePicture` as follows: `this.takePicture.bind(this);`. You never invoke `this.takePicture` though.